# Using vars_files conditionally in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

What I am trying to achieve is something like following

vars_files:
- "{{ 'vars/vars.yml'  if condition==True else 'vars/vars1.yml' }}"

Can someone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: did you try what you showed?  What happened?  Build a very simple playbook to test it

Answer (score 4):

*vars_files* is a [playbook keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). The conditions can't be applied to keywords. Instead, an option would be using [*include_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) which is a task. For example

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars: vars/vars1.yml
      when: condition|bool
```

---

Notes

- The directory *vars* in the path is not necessary. See [The magic of ‘local’ paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths)
- See [CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars)
- Make sure there is no problem with the higher [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). If there is a  problem with the higher precedence of *include_vars* open a new question with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) details. There are many options for how to solve it depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
vars_files: 
- vars/{{ 'vars' if condition==True else 'vars1' }}.yml
```